# Search by changed content in TFS VS 2010 or VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a file which has been modified several times in different versions of the product. I would like to search all the changesets in the history of the file and see if a particular string "CK_CLIENT_TIMEZONE" has been part of the changes in any changeset.

Currently I am doing this by viewing the history of the file and comparing two adjacent changesets manually. It will be excellent if there was a way to search only the changes in history and see which changeset had the change I'm interested in.

Comment: I am afraid you'll need to script that using Powershell and the Client Object Model. I do not remember any feature in the product that can do this natively.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you. That's an opportunity.